# Elasticsearch 7.5.2, paginating, getting "Rejecting mapping update as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [_doc, _search]"

Tags: elasticsearch, pagination

Elaticsearch 7.5.2, I'm trying to paginate over a query.
The first POST goes fine, and returns me a scroll_id.
Then I loop for next page like this:

```
POST /my_index/_search/scroll
{
  "scroll": "1m",
  "scroll_id":"DnF1ZXJ5VGhlbkZldGNoaQAAAAAGt4QrFlNTRFVveG80UlhTQ1M1RmVDS2x4Y1EAAAAABreELBZTU0RVb3hvNFJYU0NTNUZlQ0tseGNRAAAAAAWsCoQWY1BrWUZhOVhRNlNBeEkwMkgyeFZtdwAAAAAFrAqFFmNQa1lGYTlYUTZTQXhJMDJIMnhWbXcAAAAABawKhhZjUGtZRmE5WFE2U0F4STAySDJ4Vm[...]"
}
```

(Note that the scroll_id is quite long, that's why I need to use a POST instead of a GET)
At that point I get a 400 error with this message:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "Rejecting mapping update to [my_index] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [_doc, _search]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason": "Rejecting mapping update to [my_index] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [_doc, _search]"
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

As if it were trying to index a document, instead of paginating a query.

Any idea...?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-scroll), this is because you need to remove the index name from the second call. Do it like this:

```
remove the index name
     |
     v
POST /_search/scroll
{
  "scroll": "1m",
  "scroll_id":"DnF1ZXJ5VGhlbkZldGNoaQAAAAAGt4QrFlNTRFVveG80UlhTQ1M1RmVDS2x4Y1EAAAAABreELBZTU0RVb3hvNFJYU0NTNUZlQ0tseGNRAAAAAAWsCoQWY1BrWUZhOVhRNlNBeEkwMkgyeFZtdwAAAAAFrAqFFmNQa1lGYTlYUTZTQXhJMDJIMnhWbXcAAAAABawKhhZjUGtZRmE5WFE2U0F4STAySDJ4Vm[...]"
}
```